# Xcode: Working copy has uncommitted changes

Tags: xcode, git

When trying to switch branch in Xcode 7 beta 3 or 6.4 I get "Working copy has uncommitted changes". If I commit or discard all changes and try again I get the same result.

**Update:**

So now I'm unable to check out another branch, whatever I try:

**`MacBook-Air:Åka Strax andreas$ git reset --hard`**

```
HEAD is now at 9190d8c omstrukturerat typer
```

**`MacBook-Air:Åka Strax andreas$ git status`**

```
HEAD detached at 9190d8c
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   "A\314\212ka Strax.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    "N\303\244rliggandeH\303\245llplatser.swift"

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

**`MacBook-Air:Åka Strax andreas$ git checkout master`**

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    Åka Strax.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

**`MacBook-Air:Åka Strax andreas$ git rm --cached "Åka Strax.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"`**

```
rm 'Åka Strax.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'
```

**`MacBook-Air:Åka Strax andreas$ git status`**

```
HEAD detached at 9190d8c
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    "\303\205ka Strax.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   "A\314\212ka Strax.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    "N\303\244rliggandeH\303\245llplatser.swift"
    "\303\205ka Strax.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"
```

---

**Initial "solved" complications:**

Here's `git status` and some commands (in order) from SO answers to similar questions:

**`MacBook-Air:Åka Strax andreas$ git status`**

```
On branch swift_2.0-tester
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/swift_2.0-tester' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    "N\303\244rliggandeH\303\245llplatser.swift"
    "\303\205ka Strax.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/"
    "\303\205ka Strax.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/"

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

**`MacBook-Air:Åka Strax andreas$ git reset --hard HEAD`**

```
HEAD is now at a69fdbe
```

**`MacBook-Air:Åka Strax andreas$ git status`**

```
On branch swift_2.0-tester
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/swift_2.0-tester' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    "N\303\244rliggandeH\303\245llplatser.swift"
    "\303\205ka Strax.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/"
    "\303\205ka Strax.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/"

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

**`MacBook-Air:Åka Strax andreas$ git add "N\303\244rliggandeH\303\245llplatser.swift"`**

```
fatal: pathspec 'N\303\244rliggandeH\303\245llplatser.swift' did not match any files
```

**`MacBook-Air:Åka Strax andreas$ git rm --cached "N\303\244rliggandeH\303\245llplatser.swift"`**

```
fatal: pathspec 'N\303\244rliggandeH\303\245llplatser.swift' did not match any files
```

I honestly don't understand what git is telling me.

Comment: What's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Git is fundamentally broken in terms of file names on certain filesystems (like HFS+). It appears naive of Git to expect all file systems to have identical requirements on file identifiers/file names. Perhaps OSX doesn't hand Git the actual file name when a file is created, although that sounds somewhat far-fetched.

I am only using this repo on OS X but I still seem to get file name encoding problems.

To solve this I'm forced to use ASCII only in my file names. Feels like going back in time.

Comment: If you set `core.quotePath` to `false` will the filenames be printed verbatim

Comment: Thank you, I upvotd your answer. But the issue continued as illustrated in my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

By default the path output from `git status` is escaped, use the filename provided by your OS (`ls .` on linux), in this case you may try `git add NärliggandeHållplatser.swift`.

For more info, see `core.quotePath` at
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html

Comment: Thanks, that configuration highlights the problem: The same letter is encoded differently and Git expects me to input the letter *in a specific encoding*. Which seems kind of idiotic.